# Inserting a variable from a batch file into a text file

Tags: variables, batch-file, insert, text-files

How would I insert a variable previously established in a batch file into a text file.  I have the inserting text into a text file down, i just cant figure out the insertion of a variable.

What I am doing

```
SET name = "Casey"
ECHO "Hey" + name  > file.txt
```

The result

```
"Hey" + name
```

What I want

```
"Hey Casey"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
SET name=Casey
ECHO "Hey %name%"  > file.txt
```

Note that there is **no spaces** before and after the **=** in

> name=Casey

Comment: did a direct copy paste and it did not work RESULT: "Hey" + "$name"

Comment: What operating system are you using?
This works great on Ubuntu for me.

Comment: Sorry I mismatch bash and batch. I'll still help you to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Too bad syntax, you need to forget other programming languages, this is Batch.

First you can't use spaces when assing values to variables, this is the way to do it:

```
SET "name=Casey"
```

Also you can do this:

```
SET "name=        Casey"
```

Second Batch don't have **ANY** concatenate operator for strings, forget + and &, & is for concatenating commands.

So this is the correct syntax:

```
SET "name=Casey"
(ECHO Hey %name%)> "file.txt"
```

Try to use () agrupation operators when Echo a numeric ending string like "MyName 2", to avoid problems in large scripts with Batch redirections.